# Sort the admin area of a Wordpress custom post type by a custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

It was easy enough to get my custom fields to show up as columns in the wp-admin area of my custom post type but now I need to sort by one of those custom fields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the [answer to this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-sort-the-admin-area-of-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-by-a-custom-field) will end up on the Wordpress stackexchange site.

Comment: It did! The answer there is wonderful just in case you happen to end up here instead.

Answer (score 0):

But of course.  This will sort posts by the value of the `pant_size` custom field:

```
$posts = query_posts('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=pant_size&order=DESC');
```

You can read more about it in [this article](http://wpengineer.com/sort-posts-custom-fields/).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Wordpress help is a waistland here. Anyway, that's for when you want to display the posts to the user, not the admin area where you can edit the custom posts and that's where I want to change the sorting. I'm thinking maybe I can do it with Javascript and make all the columns sortable while I'm at it but that probably won't work because of paging.